# how to get a td value of a table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a aspx file like has HTML like  below:

[image]

I want to get the value 37.23961( as seen above).

how do i get this value ( td with iindex 6 of table 'gridview2) using javascript ?

MyHTML:

```
<table rules="all" id="GridView2" style="width:542px;border-collapse:collapse;" border="1" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">hname</th>
        <th scope="col">haddress</th>
        <th scope="col">hphone</th>
        <th scope="col">hhours</th>
        <th scope="col">hrating</th>
        <th scope="col">hlat</th>
        <th scope="col">hlong</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Kaiser Permanante</td>
        <td>200 Fremont boulevard</td>
        <td>5105199000</td>
        <td>Mon-Fri : 8:00 AM - 11:00 PM, Sat, Sun: 10:00 AM- 6:00PM</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>37.23961</td>
        <td>-121.800278</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please copy-paste your HTML so we can manipulate it?

Comment: Is the value always in the 6th column of the second row in the table?

Comment: `alert(document.getElementById("GridView2").getElementsByTagName("td")[5].innerHTML)` try this

Comment: Check out my answer and my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/2xww81m8/

Comment: Please find the answers below and close this question by marking the answer as acepted whichever satisfied your needs.

Comment: Use table innerHTML grabber http://jsfiddle.net/wxhajtbn/1/

Answer (score 4):

First access the appropriate `tr` and in that, access the appropriate `td`. Checkout the snippet below:

```js
var tr = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[1];

var td = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")[5];

var td_text = td.innerHTML;  // here is "37.23961"

document.getElementById("fetched").innerHTML = td_text;
```

```css
#fetched{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table rules="all" id="GridView2" style="width:542px;border-collapse:collapse;" border="1" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">hname</th>
      <th scope="col">haddress</th>
      <th scope="col">hphone</th>
      <th scope="col">hhours</th>
      <th scope="col">hrating</th>
      <th scope="col">hlat</th>
      <th scope="col">hlong</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Kaiser Permanante</td>
      <td>200 Fremont boulevard</td>
      <td>5105199000</td>
      <td>Mon-Fri : 8:00 AM - 11:00 PM, Sat, Sun: 10:00 AM- 6:00PM</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>37.23961</td>
      <td>-121.800278</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<label>Fetched TD content: </label><span id="fetched"></span>
```

Comment: I am using script tags in aspx file.

Do i have to use something like <%- <%= <% to make the script run or something? :-/

Comment: @MonicaThaneer I never worked with ASPX but you may take a look at the official documentation about it: [Using JavaScript Along with ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479011.aspx)

Comment: @MonicaThaneer, put your script inside "script" tag. that will be enough.

Answer (score 1):

check with this code using jquery.if possible provide jsfiddle.

```
$('#GridView2').find('td:eq(6)').html();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2xww81m8/)

Comment: This is not a jQuery question.

Comment: I have suggested to use jquery . which makes code easy in one step.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value using

```
var gridTable = document.getElementById("GridView2");
if(gridTable && gridTable.rows[1].cells[5]){
      var result=gridTable.rows[1].cells[5].innerText;
}
```

If you want the actual float value and not string, then you can parse it.

```
parseFloat(result);
```

If you want to get all the row's 6th column value, You can refer this codepen: http://codepen.io/bhuvana/pen/OPyjWw

Answer (score 1):

```js
function myData(){
x = document.getElementById("GridView2").rows.length;

for(i=1;i<x;i++){
 var tr = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i];
 var tdl = tr.getElementsByTagName("td").length;
 
 for(j=0;j<tdl;j++){
  var td = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")[j];
     alert(td.innerHTML);
 }
}
}
```

```html
<table rules="all" id="GridView2" style="width:542px;border-collapse:collapse;" border="1" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">hname</th>
        <th scope="col">haddress</th>
        <th scope="col">hphone</th>
        <th scope="col">hhours</th>
        <th scope="col">hrating</th>
        <th scope="col">hlat</th>
        <th scope="col">hlong</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Kaiser Permanante</td>
        <td>200 Fremont boulevard</td>
        <td>5105199000</td>
        <td>Mon-Fri : 8:00 AM - 11:00 PM, Sat, Sun: 10:00 AM- 6:00PM</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>37.23961</td>
        <td>-121.800278</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button onclick="myData()">click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("td")[6]
```

Basically, you're getting all the elements with the tag name "td", and the brackets on the end specify which element to choose.

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the HTML content of the 6th  element in the markup which can be done in the following way

```
document.getElementsByTagName("td")[6].innerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

Do give ID to your TDs, if you are generating table, you can give index ids.

```
For example :
for(var i=0;i<rows;i++)
{
tableCells = tablesCells + "<td id=td" + i + ">"+data[i] + "</td>";
}
```

Then you can identify what index's value you need and use following methods to get values

```
var tdElem = document.getElementById ( "td" +id );
var tdText = tdElem.innerHTML;
OR


$("#td"+id).html();
```

Comment: Sry I have nil knowledge about jquery

i am getting a synatx error at 'in' for line in JQuery

Comment: you can use javascript, syntax given above

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JavaScript, then [document.querySelectorAll(*css selector*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) is your option. Get all td element that is the sixth child of its parent:

```
var tds = document.querySelectorAll("#GridView2 td:nth-child(6)");
```

To get its text, you may want to loop it.

```
for (var i = 0, len = tds.length; i < len; i++) {
  alert(tds[i].textContent || tds[i].innerText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be really easier if you would use jQuery. But as you have your specific index and the table structure is fixed you can have your job done simply using nested [***.getelementsbytagname()***](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbytagname.asp)

***javaScript :***

```
alert(document.getElementById("GridView2")
    .getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0]
    .getElementsByTagName("tr")[1]
    .getElementsByTagName("td")[5]
    .innerHTML);
```

***jQuery***

If you do prefer jQuery you may have a look,

```
$("#GridView2 tbody tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(6)").html();
```

[***javaScript / jQuery***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/741jtsmq/)

Answer (score 0):

I have all the td's from the table in the same `class="tds"` and with that way i take all the data with the for loop.

```
   var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("tds");
        for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
            (function(index) {
                console.log(elements[index].lastChild.data);   
            });
        })(i);
    }
```

In your situation:

```
var sixth = elements[5].lastChild.data;
```