# How to assign the value of an input field to a button in a jinja list

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

I am currently building a web app with flask. In a table, I want to create buttons that get assigned the value of an input field, but in a table created with jinja. Normaly this would have been possible with this code but since it is a jinja table I can't find a way to do this. Can anybody help?

```html
<tbody>
  {% for itemname in itemnames%}
  <tr>
    <td class="text-start"><button class="item btn" type="submit" name="item" value="{{itemname.name}}">{{itemname.name}}</button></td>
    <td class="text-start"><input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control mx-auto w-auto" id="{{itemname.amount}}" name="amount" placeholder={{itemname.amount}} value="{{itemname.amount}}" type="text"></td>
    <td class="text-start"><button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="add" onclick="getInputValue();">+</button></td>
  </tr>
  <script>
    function getInputValue() {
      // Selecting the input element and get its value
      var inputVal = document.getElementById("{{itemname.amount}}").value;

      // Displaying the value
      alert(inputVal);
    }
  </script>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit, removed the first way**

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_navigation.asp

Use dom navigation starting from the button to the input

```html
<td class="text-start"><input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control mx-auto w-auto" id="{{itemname.amount}}" name="amount" placeholder={{itemname.amount}} value="{{itemname.amount}}" type="text"></td>
    <td class="text-start"><button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="add" onclick="getInputValue(this);">+</button></td>
```

```js
function getInputValue(e) {
     var input = e.previousSibling.value
     alert(input)
  </script>
```

Comment: If you want you could also check my answer here and check if it would be any help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71877751/creating-clickable-table-that-sends-selected-row-data-as-a-post-request-to-a-fla/71878918#71878918